# Not able to connect AX 2009 Dynamics business connector

Tags: c#, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, business-connector

We are using AX 2009 Business connector for our .net application to get the data from AX.once in a week or month it is not able to connect AX using business connector in production environment. Below is the error logs we found during the connectivity issue.
Error log
"2018-09-05 19:01:51,019 [56] ERROR Instrumentation.Logging.Logger AX
Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.LogonFailedException: You are not a recognized user of Microsoft Dynamics AX. Contact your system administrator for help."

and event viewer log as below
"Unable to connect to an Application Object Server. A server name may not be specified correctly in the client configuration, or the server specified may not be available."

After restarting Application pool our application is working fine . Can any one help me why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

On the server with the business connector installed, locate the hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) and add the IP address of the AOS server which the business connector is pointing to.

I had a similar problem back in the days where my .Net web application from time to time lost the connection to the AOS.